# Using Fopen to read a file in C and getting specific values from it

Tags: c#, c

I have a C Input File which I am reading with Fopen . . . .
the file looks like this:

```
Nick
Sullivan
24
lat  long north
1002.3 341.23 123.9
1002.3 341.23 123.9
1002.3 341.23 123.9
1002.3 341.23 123.9
1002.3 341.23 123.9
...... tons of lines like this
```

My goal here is to print in my C file
     Name: Nick Sullivan
     Age: 24 years old
     Number of GPS Points: [Here the counting of all the number line below]

Current I have:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s\n%s\n%s", FirstName, LastName, age);
      printf("Full Name :%s %s\n",FirstName, LastName);
      printf("Age: %s years old", age);
```

How can I count how many lines below LAT LONG NORTH it has ?

Comment: Do not use `fscanf` to read lines. Use `fgets`.`

Comment: To count just call fgets in a loop until it returns NULL (and increment a counter along the way...)

Comment: Thanks, added the fgets, and it worked! Can you try upvoting comment, asI cant ask more questions! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with I'll recommend `fgets` and `sscanf` instead of `fscanf`. It gives you a better control of the reading process. Especially you should avoid `fscanf` with `%s` as it opens up for buffer overflow.

Using `fgets` you can do something like:

```
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 256

char str[MAX_LINE_LEN];
char FirstName[MAX_LINE_LEN];
char LastName[MAX_LINE_LEN];
unsigned age;
size_t lineCount = 0;

// Open file and check for succes

if (fgets(FirstName, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp) == NULL)
    exit(1);  // error

if (fgets(LastName, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp) == NULL)
    exit(1);  // error

if (fgets(str, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp) == NULL)
    exit(1);  // error

if (sscanf(str, "%u", &age) != 1)
    exit(1);  // error

if (fgets(str, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp) == NULL)  // Skip the "lat  long north"
    exit(1);  // error

// Count lines;
float f1, f2, f3;
while(fgets(str, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp) != NULL)
{
    if (sscanf(str, "%f %f %f", &f1, &f2, &f3) != 3) break;
    ++lineCount;
}
```